# Django Q not working with strings and DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

So, I need a 'Following' system in Django, and have a model:

```py
class Following(models.Model):
    Follower = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Follower')
    GettingFollowed = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Status = models.CharField(
        choices=[
            ['Pending', 'Pending'],
            ['Accepted', 'Accepted'],
            ['Declined', "Declined"]
        ],
        max_length=30
    )
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['Follower', 'GettingFollowed']
```

and I need a way do display requests as "Pending" only, and using a Q such as

```py
CurrentUser = request.auth.token.userpofile
Friends = Following.objects.filter(Q(Follower = CurrentUser)|Q(Status = 'Pending'))
```

this throws all results with `Follower = CurrentUser` and doesn't filter by Status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to recommend you use `IntergerField` instead of `CharField` for improving performance when using filter as Q.

```
# Define status type
PENDING, ACCEPTED, DECLINED = range(3)
STATUS_TYPE_OPTIONS = (
    (PENDING, 'Pending'),
    (ACCEPTED, 'Accepted'),
    (DECLINED, 'Declined')
)

class Following(models.Model):
    Follower = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Follower')
    GettingFollowed = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Status = models.IntegerField(
        choices=STATUS_TYPE_OPTIONS,
        default=PENDING,
        verbose_name="status type"
    )
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['Follower', 'GettingFollowed']
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly, and took 3 ms off query time as well!

Comment: Good to hear that, one more recommendation is you should use snake_case style to name Python variables instead CamelCase ^^